# Import modules with class

Tags: python, class, oop, module

Problem: I have got a script with a class and some functions in a folder (with __ init __ .py). In root folder I have got a **main.py** script.

In main script I called the module with the model:

```
import folder.script
```

And, I called module with the model:

```
folder.script.class.function()
```

'class' is the class of script used as a module. 'function' is the function relative to class.

But, I receive an output error:

```
TypeError: unbound method function() must be called with class instance as first argument
```

(got nothing instead)

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Let us see your source code

Comment: Try `folder.script.class().function()`

Comment: Note: Python is not Java, functions do not *have* to live in classes. If you have a function  that doesn't need to maintain state, just put it in the module, **not** in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `function` requires that there first be an instance of `class` before you can use it.  Make your code like this:

```
folder.script.class(...).function()
```

By adding `(...)` after the class name, you create an instance of that class.

However, it might be better to do:

```
var = folder.script.class(...)
var.function()
```

That way, you can use the class instance later in the script under the name of `var`.

Or, if `function` is constructed in such a way that it doesn't actually need a class instance to work, why not move it out of the class altogether and place it right in the module?  You should only place functions in classes if they need to be there in order to work properly.

*Note:* `...` means to put what is needed.  I don't know what arguments (if any) `class.__init__` takes.  If it takes none, doing just `()` will work.